# How could someone replicate the Follow/Unfollow hover action on Twitter's website using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, button, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

When you look at who you're following on [Twitter](https://www.twitter.com), the buttons change from Follow to Unfollow (switch from green to red AND change from check-mark to x-mark).

How would I replicate this on my website? I realize it's probably a combination of bootstrap-css and bootstrap-buttons.js, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: As far as I know, Twitter actually doesn't use Bootstrap for twitter.com; I think they only use it for small, mostly-internal projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bootstrap-buttons.js is a new feature in Twitter Bootstrap. But you can also do it manually using jQuery.

Here's a button (green)

```
<a href="#" class="follow btn success" onmouseover="change_btn();">&check; Following</a>
```

now, you need to change the class and content of the button on hover,:

```
// Javascript File
function change_btn(){

$('.follow').removeClass("success");
$('.follow').addClass("danger");
$('.follow').html("&cross; UnFollow");

}
```

This script will remove and add classes to change the background of the button and also changes the content in it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question but I think I figured it out a little bit by checking the element of the following button on Twitter.com. it can be done in pure CSS, for example:

```
<div class="follow-button-combo is-following">
  <a href="xxxx" class="btn">
    <div class="is-following">Following</div>
    <div class="to-follow">Follow</div>
    <div class="to-unfollow">Unfollow</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

the button will contain 3 different action texts at the same time.
and we can use CSS to hide 2 of them, according to the condition:

in SCSS:

```
/* in SCSS file */
.follow-button-combo {
  /* Following, make the combo's class = "is-following"
     so only the "Following" text is shown */
  &.is-following {
    .btn {@extend .btn-success;}
    .is-following {display:block;}
    .to-follow {display:none;}
    .to-unfollow {display:none;}
    /* when hover, only the "Unfollow" text is shown */
    &:hover {
      .btn{@extend .btn-danger;} /* the button color changes to red */
      .is-following {display:none;}
      .to-follow {display:none;}
      .to-unfollow {display:block;} } 
  }

  /* Not following, make the combo's class = "not-following"
     so only the "Follow" text is shown */
  &.not-following {     
    .is-following {display:none;}
    .to-follow {display:block;}
    .to-unfollow {display:none;}    
    /* when hover, nothing changes */
  }
}
```