# twitter-like follow button, hover action

Tags: jquery, hover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could someone replicate the Follow/Unfollow hover action on Twitter's website using Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455256/how-could-someone-replicate-the-follow-unfollow-hover-action-on-twitters-websit)

I'm creating a Twitter-like follow button. The code is at http://jsfiddle.net/RQSsz/9/.

```
<button type="submit" value="" class="btn follow following " title="In bookmarks">
    <i class="bookmarked"></i><span>In bookmarks</span>
</button>
<button type="submit" value="" class="btn follow unfollow displaynone" title="From bookmarks">
    <i class="unfollow"></i><span>From bookmarks</span>
</button>

$('.btn.follow.following').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        $(".btn.follow.following").toggleClass("displaynone");
        $(".btn.follow.unfollow").toggleClass("displaynone");
    } else {
        $(".btn.follow.following").toggleClass("displaynone");
        $(".btn.follow.unfollow").toggleClass("displaynone");
    }
});
```

I have an issue with the flicker of the button. What am doing wrong?

Comment: Done. Thank you for the clarification about accepted answers!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you understand the benefits of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hiding of the button triggers the hover event, which causes the button to be hidden, which triggers the hover event, etc, etc, etc.

Firstly, your selector is nonsense. You want to select both your buttons:

```
$('.follow, unfollow')
```

Secondly, why bother toggling a class? This means you are depenent on an initial state. Just use the `show()` / `hide()` method instead:

```
$(".btn.follow.following").hide();
$(".btn.follow.unfollow").show();
```

and

```
$(".btn.follow.following").show();
$(".btn.follow.unfollow").hide();
```

I've modified you demo and it now should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mGGae/1/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$('.btn.follow.following').live({
    mouseover : function(event) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(".btn.follow.unfollow").show();
    }
    mouseout: function(event) {
        $(".btn.follow.unfollow").hide();
        $(this).show();        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button.follow").hover(
 function () {
  $(this).html($("<i class='bookmarked'></i><span>From bookmarks</span>"));
 }, 
 function () {
  $(this).html("<i class='bookmarked'></i><span>IN boomarks</span>");
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question but I think I figured it out a little bit by checking the element of the following button on Twitter.com. it can be done in pure CSS, for example:

```
<div class="follow-button-combo is-following">
  <a href="xxxx" class="btn">
    <div class="is-following">Following</div>
    <div class="to-follow">Follow</div>
    <div class="to-unfollow">Unfollow</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

the button will contain 3 different action texts at the same time.
and we can use CSS to hide 2 of them, according to the condition:

in SCSS:

```
/* in SCSS file */
.follow-button-combo {
  /* Following, make the combo's class = "is-following"
     so only the "Following" text is shown */
  &.is-following {
    .btn {@extend .btn-success;}
    .is-following {display:block;}
    .to-follow {display:none;}
    .to-unfollow {display:none;}
    /* when hover, only the "Unfollow" text is shown */
    &:hover {
      .btn{@extend .btn-danger;} /* the button color changes to red */
      .is-following {display:none;}
      .to-follow {display:none;}
      .to-unfollow {display:block;} } 
  }

  /* Not following, make the combo's class = "not-following"
     so only the "Follow" text is shown */
  &.not-following {     
    .is-following {display:none;}
    .to-follow {display:block;}
    .to-unfollow {display:none;}    
    /* when hover, nothing changes */
  }
}
```